# socket not connecting

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, remote-control

I made a python program for PC remote controlling and when I use the `socket.gethost()` to get the ip for the server it works fine but if I use `192.168...` it does not even connect (the PC's are on the same wifi though).

I think the code is correct because if I try to connect the same PC as a host and as a client it works normally, so I wanted to know what ip I should use and if I want to use it on different Wi-Fi's what should ip should I use?

If you need the code just ask.

I use Kali.

Answer (score 1):

for the bind address on the server file use `0.0.0.0` if you want to connect to it from a different device. then use its ip 192.168... to connect from the other device.

Comment: Thanks, that works on lan, what should I change to connect from different networks?

Comment: i believe you just need to port forward and then use your public ip to connect.